# Stuck at many-to-many relationship in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many

I am doing a simple Shopping application as my project. I am stuck to maintain a many-to-many relationship.

I have to store all the details of a user transaction in some tables with relationship. Here are some important columns.

```
User_Id -- Foreign key from user table
Associated_Product_Id -- Foreign key from product table
Associated_Product_Quantity -- Not Null
```

For more simplicity

```
user1         product1         5 pieces
user1         product2         2 pieces
user1         product3         1 piece
user2         product1         2 pieces
user2         product3         3 pieces
```

Here one user can buy many products and one product can be bought by many users. So I am totally confused, how to manage this table. I mean which one is primary key here.

It doesn't matter in how many tables I will manages these information. But I need to manage thes information. Can anybody give a rough idea on managing this. So that I could work on that direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Your table is setup correctly, assuming that you need to store the price paid at the time an item is bought (otherwise, the Amount would be in the `product` table).  What is it you need assistance with? As you have it, when a `User_Id` purchases a `Associated_Product_id`, you would create a row with the quantity purchased and the price paid.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The amount is in the product table only. Can you help me in setting up the transaction table and its relationship with the user and product table? See my updated question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing a shopping application as a project, you may want to consider adding a fourth table into your schema, to hold Orders.

Your tables might then look something like:

```
Users
-----
UserID (PK)
... (Other user details)

Product
-------
ProductID (PK)
... (Other product details)

Order
-----
OrderID (PK)
UserID (FK)
OrderDate

OrderLine
---------
OrderID (PK)
ProductID (PK)
OrderQuantity
```

This would then enable you to see how many units of a product a user bought on any given date, rather than just how many units that user has ever bought.

Comment: In OrderLine table is the OrderID is foreign key from Order table and ProductID from Product table? Please confirm it.

Comment: In the OrderLine table as shown, the primary key for the table is a compound key composed of OrderID and ProductID. (Alternatively, you could have a separate OrderLineNumber as part of the primary key, and have ProductID as a foreign key; however, that would be more complicated.)

Comment: Yeah I understood that both OrderID and ProductID are composite PK for OrderLine table, but my question is whether these two columns will refer from Order and Product table are just the values.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar: I can't make sense of your last comment. To answer the question I *think* you are asking, OrderLine.OrderID links to Order.OrderID and OrderLine.ProductID links to Product.ProductID.

Answer (score 1):

For the transaction you just need 1 table - something like you just posted.

If you need to know what products a certain user bought, you query this table for `User_Id`, and if you need to know by what users a certain product was bought, you query the table for `Associated_Product_Id`. 
(I assume that you already have your table for producs and users, since you are referencing the IDs here.)

You should of course add a column `Transaction_Id` or something similar, to uniquely identify a transaction.

Comment: BUt how I will manage the Transaction_Id in that table? E.g. Transaction1-user1-here how I will write set of products bought by user. As MySQL has no Array supported.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. If you want to list all the products that a user with a certain User_Id (e.g. 1234) bought, you query it with `SELECT Associated_Product_Id FROM Transactions WHERE User_Id = 1234;` This will return a set of product IDs. (I assume here that your transactions table is called 'Transactions'.)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want three tables:

1) User Table
2) Product Table
3) Transaction Table

User 1:m Transaction
Transaction 1:m Product

Transaction will need keys to link both User & Product

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't let you use many-to-many relationships in only two tables. You have to create a third table for the two tables you want to relate to.

The third table will simply contain foreign keys for the products and users (plus an ID for each transaction).

A simple example woulc be:

```
CREATE TABLE Product_User (
    trans_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product_id INT NOT NULL, 
    user_id INT NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES Product_table (productid), 
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User_table (userid)
);
```

With the corresponding names for the tables and the id fields.

Comment: You exactly got my point. Can you please suggest, how to? Because in Oracle I could easily manage it.But in Mysql I am totally confused.

Comment: I have just added a sample SQL query to my answer. check it out ;)

Comment: the above code sample will create a table called `Product_table` with the three fields `trans_id`, `product_id`, and `user_id`. `product_id` will be a foreign key to the relevant `id` in your Product table, and `user_id` will be one to your User table. In case you're totally unfamiliar with MySQL ;)